# Why NLogTraceListener ignores nlog async wrapper?

Tags: c#, web-services, asynchronous, asmx, nlog

I use NLog for loging asmx service events.
Part of web.config:

```
<system.diagnostics>
    <trace autoflush="true" />
    <sources>
        <source name="System.Web.Services.Asmx">
            <listeners>
                <add name="nlog" type="NLog.NLogTraceListener, NLog" />
            </listeners>
        </source>
    </sources>
    <switches>
        <add name="System.Web.Services.Asmx" value="All" />
    </switches>
</system.diagnostics>
```

I use asyncWrapper in my nlog.config:

```
<targets>
    <target name="AsyncTarget" xsi:type="AsyncWrapper">
        <target xsi:type="File" fileName="//192.168.0.5/Logs/file.log" layout="${message}"/>
    </target>
</targets>

<rules>
    <logger name="*" writeTo="AsyncTarget"/>
</rules>
```

All logs are logged successfully. **10 requests** (simulated at the same time) **takes about 1 second**.

**The problem is when the log target IP is unreachable. Then the 10 requests** (simulated at the same tame) **takes about 10 second**.

It seems like async wrapper is not working.

The problem is gone when I change NLog.NLogTraceListener listener to System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener in my web.config. Then the 10 request takes about 1 second (when the log target IP is unreachable). But I need to use NLog.

The problem is gone when I disable asmx loging from web.config an log only with nlog methods in code, then 10 requests takes about 1 second (when the log target IP is unreachable) and async wrapper works. But I need to use asmx source log.

Do you have any ideas how to solve this problem?

Comment: See also https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/2558

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to add the disableFlush-setting:

```
<add name="nlog" type="NLog.NLogTraceListener, NLog" disableFlush="true" />
```

The current default value in NLog 4.4 is a shotgun ready to shoot yourself in the foot, and will be changed with NLog 4.5